# NextJs 13 call variable from another page in the same layout

Tags: next.js13

i have project structure like this

```
app
 |- components
       |-header.tsx
       |- footer.tsx
       |- sidebar.tsx
 |- dashboard
       |- layout.tsx
       |- page.tsx
```

I merge dashboard and components into one window/page using dashboard/layout.tsx

here is my dashboard/layout.tsx

```js
export default function DashboardLayout({ children }: any) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header></Header>
            <div className="grid  h-[700px]">
                <div className="col-span-2">
                    <Sidebar></Sidebar>
                </div>
                <div className="col-span-4 bg-gray-100">
                    {children}
                    <Footer></Footer>
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>
    )
}
```

my dashboard.tsx

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    const activeItem = 'dashboard';

    return (
        <div>
           this is dashboard
   </div>
   )
   }
```

what I want to do is call activeItem properties from sidebar.tsx
I have tried this way on sidebar.tsx

```
import Dashboard from "../dashboard/page"

export default function Sidebar() {
    return (
<div>{activeItem}</div>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Yo cannot access variables inside components like that. In your case it looks like activeItem could be part of the url and you could read it from there (maybe via https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname) But maybe it also makes sense to read about sharing data between components in general: https://react.dev/learn#sharing-data-between-components

Comment: well sharing layout didn't mean you will share props, you still need to pass this props from somewhere in React, unless it's a global scope like window. Now React have no clue where this activeItem is coming from.

Comment: @errnesto Thank you. I was able to achieve my goal using the approach you suggested.